# jQuery firefox issue with different servers

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, apache, firefox

I'm developing a simple voting system for my site with jQuery. When I tested it on my local (own PC server), it all worked fine (on IE, Firefox and Chrome). When I uploaded to my main server, Firefox gave me an error.

Considering that Firefox works fine on my local server, it has to do with the difference in servers...

This is the function:

```
$("a.vote_up").click(function(){
//get the id
the_id = $(this).attr('id');

// show the spinner
$(this).parent().html("<img src='layout/images/spinner.gif'/>");

//fadeout
$("div#"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vote.php?action=up&id="+the_id,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("span#vp_container"+the_id).html(msg);
            $("span#vp_container"+the_id).fadeIn();
            //remove the spinner
            $("div#"+the_id).remove();

        }
    });
});
```

The function basically votes something up. In vote.php is a simple SQL function that adds 1 to a variable. simple.

What happens on my main webserver is that it doesn't remove the spinner. It keeps showing the spinner. OR it keeps on loading, OR the spinner doesn't get removed.

My main server is running on:
PHP 5.2.5
Apache 2.0.63
MySQL 5.0.77

My local server is:
PHP 5.1.4
Apache 2.0.58
MySQL 5.0.22

---

I don't know where to start looking. I have no idea what is causing the problem!

It is happening on Firefox 3.0.8.

Comment: "Firefox gave me an error" : it would be really useful to know what the error is

Comment: We do need an error to see what's wrong. Right now it can be anything including your vote.php script.

Comment: I'm sorry. It doesn't give me an error message. I just meant to say that it has an error. The error being the spinner that keeps on spinning.

I just don't understand why it works on my local server WITH firefox, IE and Chrome, but on my main server, it only works with IE and Chrome.

Comment: So the error console in FF has no errors? Do you use firebug? What does that tell you?

Comment: You're going to have to do a bit of your own debugging.  the first thing I'd check for is invocation of vote.php.  Install firebug.  Is the request being made?  If so, what's the response?

Comment: try visiting vote.php directly and make sure it is working correctly and has correct permissions and everything. It appears that the changes you are looking for occur on the success of that.

Comment: vote.php works fine. checked it. I installed firebug and tested it out. I also removed the spinner and the fades. it turns out, that the problem is lies with this function:

$("span#vp_container"+the_id).html(msg);

It doesn't seem to want to update the span tag... I ran firebug on my local server too. When I click to vote, it changes it correctly, but on my main, it doesn't want to change it. Could it be a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

As both Firefox and jQuery operate on the client side, a different server does not make any difference.

Are the javascript, html and vote.php file all located in the same directory?

Seems like a path problem to me, but that is hard to tell without more information (code).

**Edit:** The server error log should tell you if it can´t locate some of the files

Comment: It is a server issue as it is the only difference between my local server (on my laptop) and my main host server. ALL the code and databases are the same.

With firefox on my local server, it works perfectly. With firefox on my main server, it fails. I've tested with IE and Chrome. With those browsers, it works on both servers.

SO: It IS an issue with firefox and my main server. As the code is exactly the same, it's a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Firebug in Firefox put

```
console.log("id=", the_id, "; msg=", msg);
```

before your

```
$("span#vp_container"+the_id).html(msg);
```

so you get to see what the returned msg is.